# Thermodynamics: distinction in physics and chemistry

Tags: thermodynamics

How do the equations and sign conventions of First Law of thermodynamics work in physics and chemistry? How to intuitively see the clear difference and understand the cause for the same?

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Why is there a need to have different sign convention in either discipline? Why is the first law expressed differently?

Comment: Basically because chemists are usually more  interested in the work done by the surroundings on their system and physicists are usually more interested in the work done by their system on the surroundings.

Comment: Comment to Chester Miller (8/12/18): @Chester Miller *physicists are
usually more interested in the work done by their system on the
surroundings.* I can't see why and when. This was true maybe in 19th
century, when thermal machines and Carnot's cycles were reasearch
subjects for physicists. IMHO chemists's convention had to be adopted by physicists as well. It makes more sense to take as positive an energy input which *increases* internal energy - be it work or heat. Incidentally, so I did almost 30 years ago, when I taught a first year university class in General Physics.

Comment: @Elio Fabri As an engineer, I strongly prefer $\Delta U=Q-W$, but maybe this is just because that is the way it was taught to me.

Comment: Elio and Chester, I also have an engineering background, and I prefer to consider all energy as a positive quantity, whereby I add to the internal energy of a system for any input and subtract from the internal energy for any output.  This leads to my preferred form of the first law as $\Delta U = (Q_{in} + W_{in}) - (Q_{out} + W_{out})$.  This is a personal preference, but I find it much less confusing than trying to remember which book or reference used which sign convention.

Answer (score 1):

In physics and engineering, the most common expression for the first law is

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

For example, the handbook for the NCEE fundamentals exam (FE) to become a professional engineer uses this equation.

In this case, $W$ is positive if work is done ***by the system*** (work out, energy out) and negative if done **on the system** (work in, energy in).

Apparently in chemistry the form is

$$\Delta U=Q+W$$

In this case $W$ is negative if work is done ***by the system*** (work out, energy out) and positive if done **on the system** (work in, energy in).

I suppose there is some historical reason for difference in work sign convention, but the bottom line it doesn’t matter which one is used as long as you are consistent. Think of it like this. If energy is going out of the system, there will be a reduction (negative change) in internal energy. If energy is going into the system, there will be an increase (positive change).

Both versions are consistent with this.

Hope this helps